# Keyboard will appeared automatically in ios 8.3 while displaying alertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

Hi I am new for ios and in my app I have added one textfeild when I tapped on it keyboard is appearing and when I click return button I want to show `alertview`.

And when I click alertview "ok" button I want to hide keyboard but it's not hiding help me please

### my code:-

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                    message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];

    [alert show];

    return YES;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSLog(@"Hello wolrd");
    [mainscrollview endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi, provide all code in drive. I will sort your issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwQkNwXzdEdnJJd0E/view u find here

Comment: I have posted your answer. It should be works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**Direct UIView**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

NSLog(@"Hello wolrd");
[yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

**ScrollView**

create the one `tapGesture` like

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap)];
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    singleTap.delegate = self;
    [yourScrollviewName addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

//method like

 -(void)singleTap
 {
   [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
   [self.view endEditing:YES];

  }

 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

NSLog(@"Hello wolrd");
 [self singleTap];
}
```

**Update**

```
   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{




UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No network connection textField"
                                                                          message:@"keyboard should not be open"
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction * cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                           [self singleTap];
                                                      }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: one more question your textfield is added in scrollview or self.view

Comment: my textfield added on scrollview

Comment: no same problem is coming again after replace ur code bro

Comment: no bro u see this project file it just small one ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104988/discussion-between-abhiram-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below function:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [maintextfeild resignFirstResponder];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                        message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.delegate = self;

        [alert show];
    });


    return YES;
}
```